# IntelliJ Git plugin can't seem to find Java Runtime

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

When trying to perform any git actions on my IntelliJ, I get the below error:

```
            0 file committed, 11 files failed to commit: Documentation updates, error message updates
            The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
            Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

Which is unusual because everything else on the editor works - the code completion, running maven, even the tests. So if I am not mistaken, IntelliJ is identifying a Java Runtime but for some reason the Git plugin is not picking it up.

Running Git in the normal terminal works fine and the application executes on the terminal. What is causing this issue?

My IntelliJ about is as follows:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-203.7717.56, built on March 15, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+8-b1145.96 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.16
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1979M
Cores: 12
```

[image: Project Structure]

[image: Module Settings]

Comment: Please check if the problem reproduces in the latest build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download . If the problem remains click on "Reload All Maven Projects" in Maven tool window and provide screenshots from "File | Project Structure | Project" and "File | Project Structure | Modules | select_your_module | Dependencies"

Comment: @EgorKlepikov added. Unfortunately I can't download new versions, corporate policy.

Comment: Please contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide the IDE logs. (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

Turns out the issue was on the Git plugin, which did not honor the $JAVA_HOME variable on my environment. Executing Git in terminal is fine, presumably because zsh/bash is honoring Java location more explicitly, but executing through Git plugin or Github failed.

Either that Git has issues picking up Java in *nix environments where env variables are more obfuscated, or my company's terrible Mac OS estate bungled the installation. Or both.